# Central Limit Theorem to approx Binomial Distribution, cannot see how they got this answer

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, central-limit-theorem

I'm doing question **b**, using the Central Limit Theorem to approximate a Binomial Distribution to calculate it's sample mean:

> There are 20 children in a class. Each flips a biased coin 15 times. The probability of getting a head is 0.25.
>
> **a** Write down the expected number of heads that each child would get.
>
> **b** Find an estimate of the probability that the mean number of heads is at most 4.

So calculate $P(X \leq 4)$ given $N_s = 20$, $n = 15$, and $p = 0.25$.

So:

mean $= np = 0.25 \times 15 = 3.75$

variance $= np(1-p) = 3.75 \times 0.75 = 2.8125$

So use CLT with $X \sim N(3.75, 2.8125/20)$

On my calculator I use the Cumulative Normal, with lower limit $-\infty$, upper limit $4$, $\sigma=\sqrt{2.8125/20}$, $\mu=3.75$

I get $0.748$, but the textbook answer is $0.0748$:

[image]

Am I right and this is a typo?

Comment: $0.0748$ is clearly far too low given $4>3.75$ and the distribution is close to symmetric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so you have indeed have $N=20,n=15,p=0.25$, so then
$$
\begin{split}
\mu      &= np      &= 15*0.25      &= 3.75 \\
\sigma^2 &= np(1-p) &= 15*0.25*0.75 &= 2.8125
\end{split}
$$
and the standard deviation to use in the Normal distribution approximation would be
$$
s = \sqrt{\sigma^2/N} = \sqrt{2.8125/20} = 0.375.
$$

You can use [Wolfram Alpha Normal CDF calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=normal+cdf+calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22NormalProbabilities%22%2C+%22z%22%7D+-%3E%224%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22NormalProbabilities%22%2C+%22mu%22%7D+-%3E%223.75%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22NormalProbabilities%22%2C+%22sigma%22%7D+-%3E%220.375%22) to see that $\mathbb{P}[X < 4] = 0.7475$.

Comment: Thanks!........

Comment: @user997112happy to help, hope you stay around and contribute to the site.